# Apache web server with the mod_rewrite module

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I installed a multisite WordPress, and it has a thing that I need: "Pretty permalinks".

So, that "Pretty permalinks" are available under:

```
* Apache web server with the `mod_rewrite` module
* Microsoft IIS 7+ web server with the URL Rewrite 1.1+ module and 
                                                        PHP 5 running as FastCGI
* Microsoft IIS 6+ using ASAPI_Rewrite
* Lighttpd using a 404 handler or mod_rewrite (see See Also)
```

I use a hosting, and just want to know (to test) if the hosting server supports this `mod_rewrite` or not.

Is there a way to find it out without admins help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your provider is using Apache httpd:

Create an `.htaccess` file with the content `RewriteEngine on`. If you get an internal server error when opening your site in a web browser, mod_rewrite is not installed or you're not allowed to use these directives in an `.htaccess` file.